# How to use android calender in my application?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to develop an application in android where i want to add events in calender through my application also to see  them from my application ,how can i do that , any tutorial or suggestion would be helpful

the logcat file is

```
06-24 10:09:17.056: ERROR/ActivityThread(610): Failed to find provider info for calendar
06-24 10:09:17.076: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(610): Shutting down VM
06-24 10:09:17.076: WARN/dalvikvm(610): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.jimblackler.readcalendar/net.jimblackler.readcalendar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at net.jimblackler.readcalendar.Example.readCalendar(Example.java:30)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at net.jimblackler.readcalendar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
06-24 10:09:17.107: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(610):     ... 11 more
06-24 10:09:17.137: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity net.jimblackler.readcalendar/.MainActivity
06-24 10:09:18.486: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406c0978 net.jimblackler.readcalendar/.MainActivity}
06-24 10:09:19.477: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:FriendService (pid 589) has died.
06-24 10:09:20.736: WARN/InputManagerService(68): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40736c08
06-24 10:09:21.236: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_CONCURRENT freed 947K, 44% free 4739K/8327K, external 1426K/1936K, paused 32ms+43ms
06-24 10:09:21.275: INFO/Process(610): Sending signal. PID: 610 SIG: 9
06-24 10:09:21.287: INFO/dalvikvm(446): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-24 10:09:21.327: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process net.jimblackler.readcalendar (pid 610) has died.
```

Comment: its an emulator for Api 2.3.1, have not tested it on device

Comment: hello emulator not supported the calender.pls try this in the device.there is no calender api in the emulater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try thsi code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use this code because when i used this code the log cat show s the error 06-24 10:09:17.056: ERROR/ActivityThread(610): Failed to find provider info for calendar

Comment: if u use this code it will show the Add event activity in the calender app.

Comment: but my application is just crashing without starting

Comment: i have put my logcat file Kannapan

Answer (score 1):

As the android calendar usually is connected to the Google Calendar, why not use the Google Calendar API? Have a look here:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/calendar/

Instead of the Google API you could also use the CalDAV Protocol, which makes it easier to switch to some other calendar backend later on.

Comment: thanx for answer , can you tell me when we use google APi does it make an independent application or we need internet to get it working

Comment: If you need this to work offline, my approach using Google Calendar will not work. In this case you have to access the sql data from the system calendar directly (which isn't as nice as using the mentioned API), here is a quite nice tutorial for doing this: http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm